# Testing a local http dev server on iphone webview

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, wkwebview

I have a web application that I am working on along with an ios app that I want to run on iphone. I am using WKWebView to render web app on ios. My website is running on my Mac right now with http. I am able to test my ios app on iphone simulator and its working as expected.

But on real device (iphone), app is not rendering my web app. I see that webview address is about:blank. I am able to render public websites like google.com etc. I am also able to access my web app using iphone browser so there shouldn't be any network issue.

Here are the things I have tried till now:

I have enabled arbitrary links using following config:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

But for some reason its not rendering at all. It feels like I am missing some other setting. My iphone is using 13.1 version of ios. I will appreciate if someone can guide me with this. Thanks.

Comment: What URL do you pass to your Web view to open? If it's `http://localhost/...` that would work only in the simulator.

Comment: @Gereon i am using ip address as mentioned in the question I am able to render webapp in iphone browser